# Git asks a password for a wrong URL , whenever I tried to excute git clone,git pull

Tags: git, github, ssh, tfs, command-prompt

Git asks a password for a wrong URL always , whenever I tried to excute git clone,git pull or git fetch.

Password for 'http://mkspks@xxx.xxx.0.23:8080':

it is wrong url,how to remove this url or discard this url.

Comment: Hi @manishkumar, how are things going? Have you tried as the suggestions shared by `@VonC`. Is it helpful to you? If it can help you solve the problem, I recommend that you can mark the answer as the solution of this topic. This may help more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to fall back to the command-line, and type:

```
cd c:\path`\to\repository
git remote set-url origin https://remote/TFS/repository/URL
```

Replace `<https://remote/TFS/repository/URL>` by the actual repository URL.

If you are using Team Explorer, you can [edit `origin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-config?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#remotes) from the Repository Settings:

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/media/git-config/remotes.png?view=azure-devops]